# As a performer, was Mozart primarily a pianist or a violinist?

Tags: history, mozart

As a performer, was Mozart primarily a pianist or a violinist?  In other words, which was his primary performing instrument?

As he gained success as a composer, did he stop performing?  If so, was it more or less sudden, or was it gradual?

What were his strengths as a performer when he was at his height as a performer?

Comment: I don’t feel secure to provide this as a full-fledged answer because I’m not a music historian, but everything I’ve read suggests he was primarily a pianist, like most composers of his day, but was certainly a good violinist as well. Actually I believe he played viola too, even later in life when he played in a string quartet with Joseph Haydn. He would have been the pianist at most if not all premieres of his piano concertos and sonatas throughout his career. In fact, the idea of a “composer” entirely separate from the idea of “performer” didn’t exist in his day.

Comment: I kind of doubt that “specific strengths as a performer” applies to this era in that way it does in ours. Instrumental performing, improvising and composing were all kind of an integrated profession at the time. He conducted any premieres of his operas, and conducted from the piano in many other performances. Superstar performers and conductors that did little, if any, composition like we have now just weren’t a thing.

Comment: @PatMuchmore - Okay, I get that composing was his main thing, but when he was young, didn't his father trot him around to perform as a child prodigy? // I appreciate your clarifying that piano was a stronger suit than violin, thanks, that was what I was confused about. // With regard to strengths as a performer -- everybody who plays beautifully excels in slightly different areas, for example: beauty of tone, dynamic contrast including bigness of sound, playfulness, virtuosity (e.g. Paganini), and related to that, the ability to make things sound easy, theatricality, tenderness, excitement,...

Comment: ... ability to improvise and make it always fresh, construct an arc leading to a climax, ability to make the audience hushed so you can hear a pin drop, show the structure clearly, make all the notes of a certain articulation have exactly the same articulation, play everything from memory, have a large repertoire ready to go at the drop of a hat, and on and on....  You won't convince me that there was no heterogeneity among virtuosos in an age gone by.

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn’t trying to convince you there was no heterogeneity among virtuosos. More like, the modern concept of “virtuoso” doesn’t really track with performers in Mozart’s day. I think that’s something that emerged over the next century, with players like Liszt that elevated the cult of the performer, eventually, to the place it would mostly be in the 20th century. I’m not sure that the same label means the same thing in these eras. At any rate, I’ve never read anything talking about his specific strengths as a pianist, the praise is tied to his composing so much.

Comment: @PatMuchmore - I couldn't find anything either which is why I asked -- but maybe I should make it a separate question. // Okay, I see what you mean, calling Mozart a virtuoso pianist doesn't meant the same thing as calling Liszt or Paganini virtuoso performers, but I think I have heard Mozart called a virtuoso performer (relative to his period, I assume).

Answer (score 3):

His primary instrument was piano. He was a child prodigy in fact. His father was his manager and at an early age he traveled all over Europe. He played for kings even for the pope I think.

Comment: Okay, I sort of knew about that, but I believe he played violin quite well too -- didn't I read somewhere that he got frustrated with being assistant concertmaster at some point?

Comment: I don’t know about the pope, but he definitely played for Marie Antoinette as a kid. @aparente001 I’ve never heard anything about him being concertmaster anywhere. When he was involved with orchestras it was as a conductor/pianist.

Comment: @PatMuchmore - *assistant* concertmaster.  Salzburg Court.  https://www.biography.com/people/wolfgang-mozart-9417115. 
 (Assistant concertmaster is just the sort of position that might make a person feel put-upon....)

Comment: @aparente001 Sorry, that’s what I meant. I *really* don’t think he ever had a gig as a violinist in an orchestra at all, but again I’m not a historian. If you can find a reference somewhere I’d definitely be interested, and I wouldn’t dismiss it out of hand, but I’ve never heard that in lots of years of study.

Comment: @PatMuchmore - Here it is again but less buried: https://www.biography.com/people/wolfgang-mozart-9417115

Comment: @aparente001 Interesting. I wonder if concertmaster meant the same thing then, sounds like it did…

Comment: @PatMuchmore - I can't imagine a different meaning.  In fact, I would guess that in those days, the position of concertmaster was even more important than it is now.

Answer (score 2):

### Assuming you're talking of W.A Mozart, Clavier

Mozart was known as a performer primarily for his Clavier playing, and that was indeed his first instrument (arguably beginning to play at the age of 3, though he certainly composed from behind it as early as 5).

His father Leopold was a violinist, and I suspect likely the one that made you think of the instrument, though Wolfgang certainly played many instruments including the violin.

Regarding comments on his appointment as assistant Concert Master I suspect that the term Concertmaster in the context given [above](https://www.biography.com/people/wolfgang-mozart-9417115) is synonymous with the term [Kapellmeister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapellmeister) (more a director of music than a principal first violinist), rather than that of a modern Concert Master in an orchestra, especially as orchestral music then was *very* differently understood and executed in that time.

---

Edit: Further research has uncovered that [there *is* in fact a difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kapellmeister#Similar_terms_and_equivalents) between a Kapellmeister and a Concertmaster (or "Konzertmeister") in this context, with the latter being somewhat less senior. I could not, however, find anything to suggest that Mozart primarily played violin in this capacity. Seeing as he was [offered a position as "Court organist and Concert Master"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart#1777%E2%80%9378:_Journey_to_Paris) while he held this position in Salzburg it would seem instead that his primary performing responsibilities were likely on the organ or a keyboard instrument, as his Salzburg position would be the prominent thing on his resume at that point.

Comment: But see http://www.kennedy-center.org/artist/composition/5202.  Anyway, tell me the major differences for an assistant section leader (first violin) between the late Baroque and the Classical.  I'm just not with you yet.

Comment: That's a great reference! As it's written to refer directly to one of his violin concertos, it's not surprising it gives us more insight into his violin playing than other articles. Odd though - the year this article places his appointment as Salzburg Concert Master, [he was in Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozart_in_Italy#Journey_to_Milan). Regardless, I don't *know* that there's a major difference, but as our current understanding of conducting didn't yet exist, I don't see any reason to favour violinists specifically as what I have to assume was essentially a conductor position...

Comment: I'd be happy to be corrected on that, though, if you have an article that deals with the nature of a ConcertMaster position during the mid classical period.

Comment: In a quartet the violinist often does most of the leading and there is no conductor.  It's possible for a small orchestra to be led this way too. // I'm not following much of what you wrote.  For example, the Wikipedia article you say agrees with you says, "Mozart finally returned to Salzburg on 15 January 1779 and took up his new appointment....  Mozart's father exchanged intense letters with his son, urging him to be reconciled with their employer."  The employer being Colloredo.  I don't know why you say that Mozart turned down the position.

Comment: What other instruments did Mozart play besides keyboard, violin and viola?  // I had the impression Mozart was one of those people who worked out his compositions mostly in his head and then wrote them down, rather than composing at the keyboard as you mentioned.

Comment: Dreadfully sorry, it appeared I skimmed that part of the article particularly badly! I've amended my answer, removing any implication that he did not take that position. While it's true that in chamber groups often the violinist or first violinist is also the director, and that **citation needed* this was probably also the case in the classical period, I see no reason to believe that being appointed specifically as the Kapellmeister (if this is indeed synonymous in this context) would imply that you're any more likely to be primarily a violinist, rather than a keyboardist.

Comment: Especially as he was appointed as "court organist and concert master" rather than "first violinist and concert master" as I'd have expected were he in charge of simply a chamber group, with his playing responsibilities being on the violin rather than a keyboard instrument...

Comment: Regarding composing from behind the clavier, this was referring to his earliest compositional work (around the age of 5) "[At the age of five, he was already composing little pieces, which he played to his father who wrote them down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Amadeus_Mozart#Family_and_childhood)"

Comment: most of my sources currently are google/wikipedia simply due to the fact that my previous research upon which my memories and therefore assumptions are based came exclusively from paper books not available for free online (to my knowlege) which currently reside on my parent's bookshelves interstate, as I have no space on my little shelves at home these days!

Comment: I don't know if tiny Mozart was already working things out in his head or if he was plunking around until he was happy with what he got.  I rather think the former.  To me, "composing from the clavier" means the latter. // I thought he was *assistant* concertmaster in Salzburg.

Comment: I would call using the clavier as a test/dictiation aid "composing from the clavier", and that's how I intended it, though I imagine getting a solid answer on whether he was plunking or head-composing specifically would be pretty impossible...

Comment: Sorry, concertmaster in Paris, assistant in Salzburg. My bad. That was the position he turned down.

Comment: About your second comment -- I'm getting confused.  About your first comment -- if I had to guess I'd say he was head-composing.  I like that term.  My reasoning: I read something that described his approach when he was older.  I know that as a mature composer he would work it all out in his head and then quickly slap it all down on paper.

Comment: Stepping back, what I really want to know is why he switched to viola, and also I wouldn't mind understanding better that stuff you wrote earlier about the role of concertmaster (historical comparison).  (I suppose a new question would be needed.)